# TypeError: Backbone.$ is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In my single page app using backbone.js, I get this error : `TypeError: Backbone.$ is undefined`  while trying to access the sync API.

The sync API was working previously. I can't find what I broke...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick is that backbone has an optional dependency on other libs for some specific features.

The `$` variable of backbone is set to this at start time :

```
Backbone.$ = root.jQuery || root.Zepto || root.ender || root.$;
```

so in this case, backbone was trying to forward some processing to jQuery (or one of the other).

Of course, this dependency implies that jQuery/X must be available **before** backbone is loaded...

Ordering jQuery and backbone loading solves the problem.

Comment: From backbonejs.org: Backbone's only hard dependency is Underscore.js ( >= 1.4.3). For RESTful persistence, history support via Backbone.Router and DOM manipulation with Backbone.View, include json2.js, and either jQuery ( >= 1.7.0) or Zepto.

Comment: @Cymen that's exactly that ! But unlike underscore dependency which is easy to spot, this one is harder to see, especially if we use jQuery along backbone but didn't care about the order.